# How would I get my final output array to be this? {"Peter", "John", "Andy", "David"} I am trying to correct the code

Tags: java, arrays, string, methods, split

```
String names  = "Peter, John, Andy, David";
String [] splitNames = names.split(",");
System.out.println(Arrays.tostring(splitNames(','));
```

I am beginner and I am trying to correct the code to the end result of my question listed. I am teaching myself from a book which has no listed details. If someone could assist that would be great.  Thank you! I think I am on the right path I am overlooking my mistake.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Java is case-sensitive so `Arrays.tostring` should probably be `Arrays.toString`. Also `splitNames` is *variable* not a *method* so instead of `splitNames(',')` you probably just want to pass `splitNames` without parenthesis.

Comment: Maybe I am too confused, but I think you should just correct this line: `System.out.println(Arrays.tostring(splitNames(','));` to `System.out.println(Arrays.toString((splitNames));`

Comment: @MostNeededRabbit That worked thank you so much! The code was a successful build.

Comment: @Pshemo you were correct also thank you as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just correct this line:

`System.out.println(Arrays.tostring(splitNames(','));`

to:

`System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitNames));`

Answer (score 1):

This is easier to accomplish with the Stream api that was introduced in Java 8:

```
System.out.println(
    Arrays.stream(splitNames)
          .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "{", "}"))
);
```

Here's a good tutorial for Stream collectors: https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-collectors